# TypeScript circular constraint in a strongly typed object

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types

I have declared an object like so:

```js
const example = {
  morning: (name) => `Good morning ${name}!`,
  evening: (name) => `Good evening ${name}!`
}
```

In its raw form, the object has strongly typed keys (I can access them using dot notation), but the values could be anything. That's why I decided to introduce a type signature:

```js
const example: {
  [K: string]: (name: string) => string;
} = {
  morning: (name) => `Good morning ${name}!`,
  evening: (name) => `Good evening ${name}!`
}
```

Now my object values are strongly typed, but the keys aren't, and I could try to access any key using dot notation without TypeScript complaining (for example, I could write `console.log(example.doesntexist)`, and I wouldn't get editor autocompletion for the object keys either). So I tried this:

```js
const example: {
  [K in keyof typeof example]: (name: string) => string;
} = {
  morning: (name) => `Good morning ${name}!`,
  evening: (name) => `Good evening ${name}!`
}
```

Now I'm getting a circular constraint error (`Type parameter 'K' has a circular constraint` and `'example' is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation`). I'm aware I could do something like this

```js
const example: {
  [K in 'morning' | 'evening']: (name: string) => string;
} = {
  morning: (name) => `Good morning ${name}!`,
  evening: (name) => `Good evening ${name}!`
}
```

but that's redundant (and I hate redundancy/code duplication). Is there a way to do what I want to?

Comment: "*but the values could be anything*" - no, they're string-returning functions. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @Bergi I want to require all values to be string-returning functions, to avoid errors down the road

Comment: why you declared type for `example` object ?, ts will infer that for you!

Comment: @Nur As I already said, I'm setting a type to require that all object values must be string-returning functions, so I can expect the same behavior from every item in my object

Comment: Plus you want auto completions right? in my knowledge you also need specified `keys` , like `let example: Record<'morning' | 'evening', () => string>;`

Comment: @SearchingSolutions If something in your code *expects* the same behavior of all functions in the object (e.g. when accepting it as a parameter), that's the place where you should declare that type. Or you can [write an assertion that checks your `example` conforms to a specific type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55046211/1048572).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this without at least some extra code.

In cases like this I usually write a *[constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) generic [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function)* helper function.  This behaves very much like the circular annotation you were trying to write:

```
const asExample = <K extends PropertyKey>(
  x: { [P in K]: (name: string) => string }
) => x;
```

This function will only accept an input whose type has keys `K` and values `(name: string) => string)` for some key-like `K` the compiler infers, and it returns the input.  Because the function is generic in `K`, the compiler will keep track of `K` instead of widening to something like `string`.

Let's test it:

```
const example = asExample({
    morning: name => `Good morning ${name}!`,
    evening: name => `Good evening ${name}!`
})

example.morning("Alice") // okay
example.day // error! 
// ---> ~~~
// Property 'day' does not exist on type
// '{ morning: (name: string) => string; evening: (name: string) => string; }'
```

You can see that `example` is known to have properties at the `morning` and `evening` keys, but not at the `day` key.

And if you try to call `asExample()` on an bad input, you'll get the errors you want:

```
const badExample = asExample({
    afternoon: name => `Good afternoon ${name}!`.length, // error!
    // --------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // number is not assignable to string
    night: "Good night everyone!" // error!
//  ~~~~~ <-- string is not assignable to (name: string) => string
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-j2JxwDhChN9dqwrrjjALcRbkHSa66u6EJ7vXBfXgAzA1MSC3osfXMr19PYgA)